How to return multiple field validation violations (`jakarta.validation.constraints`) in Spring Boot REST API?
The context:
I have a REST API in my Spring Boot backend app. This REST API has HTTP POST endpoint with a request body. This request body as a java DTO class contains several fields (attributes). I added jakarta.validation.constraints annotations like @NotNull @NotEmpty and others to these fields to validate input data.
Now:
If any of these fields violate these jakarta.validation.constraints annotations constraints it immediately throw an exception which of course I catch with ExceptionHandler class which return HTTP 400 Bad Request with the proper error message. The issue is that with that approach I cannot provide all fields validation violations to user to give the user the whole understanding which fields input are incorrect which are correct because an exception is thrown after just validation first wrong input.
I need:
I need that I have opportunity to send the user an error message with all all fields validation violations.

My app has:

org.springframework boot 3.2.5 version

java 17



Please specify in your question additional information for which Spring Boot version you are using.

@M.Deinum sure, I will update the question with this info now.

@M.Deinum added your requested additional information. :-)

Spring Boot 3+ supports Spring Framework 6, which added support for Problem JSON, which can easily support reporting the fields back. See Spring Framework and Spring Boot documentation.

You can use the org.springframework.validation.Validator instance to validate an object manually and get all the errors. Here is an example:
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ValidateServiceImpl implements ValidateService {

private Validator validator;

@Autowired
public ValidateServiceImpl(@Qualifier("defaultValidator")Validator validator) { // 1
    this.validator = validator;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(Object bean, String objectName) {
    BeanPropertyBindingResult validateResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(bean, objectName); // 2
    validator.validate(bean, validateResult); // 3
    boolean isValid = !validateResult.hasErrors(); // 4
    if(!isValid && log.isDebugEnabled()){
        log.debug("{} is not valid. ObjectName: {} Errors:{}", bean, objectName, validateResult.getAllErrors()); // 5
    }
    return isValid;
}}


First, inject the default validator which is created by spring boot;
Declare an BeanPropertyBindingResult to hold the validation result;
Validate the object;
Check if there are any errors;
If there are, get all errors from the validateResult. After that you can return the errors to the client;


Overly complex, just add BindingResult to the controller method will achieve the same without relying on an additional service to do the validation.

Maybe there're people who need the manual way.

If you are using Spring MVC you shouldn't need this as it will only add complexity.

Spring Boot 3+ introduced support for Problem Details, or rather Spring Framework 6 added this and has a whole infrastructure for this.
Spring Boot makes it quite easy to enable this support in the properties by adding spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled=true to your application.properties.
Now this might not totally expose the fields but by adding an extended ResponseEntityExceptionHandler which overrides the handleMethodArgumentNotValid and extends the response with details. Although I think in recent versions the details of the specific fields are already added automatically.
